# get the second value from json.stringfy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, alert

I am using

```
JSON.stringy(data.message)
```

and getting value like this

```
[
  {
     "code":"PasswordTooShort",
     "description":"Passwords must be at least 6 characters."
  }
]
```

I want to get the value of description in my alert message 
how can i do this

Comment: @MohsinMuzawar Your code will not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you do not need `JSON.stringify`, but `JSON.parse`. `JSON.stringify` returns a `JSON` representation of your object.

You need to get the first element in array, because your `obj` is an `array` and then access it's property

```js
var obj = [{"code":"PasswordTooShort","description":"Passwords must be at least 6 characters."}];

alert(obj[0].description);
```

Answer (score 2):

> By using javasript json parser

```js
var obj  = JSON.parse('{ "code":"PasswordTooShort", "description":"Passwords must be at least 6 characters." }');
alert(obj['description'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
    var _array=[{"code":"PasswordTooShort",
                 "description":"Passwords must be at least 6 characters."}];
    // Since there is only one object in the array so doing _array[0]
   _array[0].description
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use a variable to save the value before do  JSON.stringy(data.message) like :

```
var description = data.message[0].description
...
alert(description)
```